# dropbox startup problem xubuntu 20.04

Tags: software-installation, xubuntu, dropbox

I downloaded and installed dropbox via dpkg -i and when I try to start I get the error: "It was not possible to start Dropbox" (generally a problem with security access?) And it produces the following log file:

```
bn.BUILD_KEY: Dropbox
bn.VERSION: 104.4.175
bn.constants.WINDOWS_SHELL_EXT_VERSION: 44
bn.is_frozen: True
machine_id: 7c62b4fd-9441-4fa4-968b-e888bbc2e077
pid: 8449
ppid: 8448
ppid exe: '/usr/bin/python3.8'
uid: 1000
user_info: pwd.struct_passwd(pw_name='tomas', pw_passwd='x', pw_uid=1000, pw_gid=1000, pw_gecos='Jose Tomas,,,', pw_dir='/home/tomas', pw_shell='/bin/bash')
effective_user_info: pwd.struct_passwd(pw_name='tomas', pw_passwd='x', pw_uid=1000, pw_gid=1000, pw_gecos='Jose Tomas,,,', pw_dir='/home/tomas', pw_shell='/bin/bash')
euid: 1000
gid: 1000
egid: 1000
group_info: grp.struct_group(gr_name='tomas', gr_passwd='x', gr_gid=1000, gr_mem=[])
effective_group_info: grp.struct_group(gr_name='tomas', gr_passwd='x', gr_gid=1000, gr_mem=[])
LD_LIBRARY_PATH: None
cwd: '/home/tomas'
     real_path='/home/tomas'
            mode=0o40755    uid=1000    gid=1000
     parent mode=0o40755    uid=0   gid=0
HOME: '/home/tomas'
appdata: '/home/tomas/.dropbox'
         real_path='/home/tomas/.dropbox'
                mode=0o100644   uid=1000    gid=1000
         parent mode=0o40755    uid=1000    gid=1000
dropbox_path: None
                        not found
              parent    not found
sys_executable: '/home/tomas/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-104.4.175/dropbox'
                real_path='/home/tomas/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-104.4.175/dropbox'
                        mode=0o100755   uid=1000    gid=1000
                parent  mode=0o40755    uid=1000    gid=1000
trace.__file__: '/home/tomas/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-104.4.175/python-packages.zip/dropbox/client/ui/common/boot_error.pyc'
                real_path='/home/tomas/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-104.4.175/python-packages.zip/dropbox/client/ui/common/boot_error.pyc'
                        not found
                parent  not found
tempdir: '/tmp'
         real_path='/tmp'
                mode=0o41777    uid=0   gid=0
         parent mode=0o40755    uid=0   gid=0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dropbox/client/main.pyc", line 7724, in main_startup
  File "dropbox/client/main.pyc", line 2940, in run
  File "dropbox/client/main.pyc", line 1547, in startup_low
  File "dropbox/client/reporting/event.pyc", line 474, in __init__
  File "dropbox/client/reporting/event.pyc", line 486, in _initialize_reporting_thread_controller
  File "dropbox/client/reporting/persistent_events.pyc", line 68, in __init__
  File "dropbox/client/reporting/persistent_events.pyc", line 228, in __init__
  File "dropbox/client/reporting/event_log.pyc", line 119, in __init__
  File "dropbox/client/main.pyc", line 1258, in safe_makedirs
  File "os.pyc", line 221, in makedirs
NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/home/tomas/.dropbox/events'
```

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to install special Dropbox plugin for Thunar by:

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install thunar-dropbox-plugin
```

and, initialize Dropbox from its icon and then use Dropbox with Thunar.

Comment: The problem persist. (note: i had installed repository universe (came preeinstalled)

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled xubuntu an it fixed the problem. Beause I had /home directory in other partition no problem with my personal data.
Sure my jobstep installation process in the first time was wrong.